# Removing ads from my iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an in app purchase in my app that removes all ads. When the in app purchase is purchased, a simple `BOOL isPremium` is set to `YES`. Now, before any view loads, it checks whether isPremium is YES or not to display ads. If it is not, it adds an `adView` in the `viewDidLoad` method. If it is premium, then I set `adView.hidden=YES`. Is this the right way to do it? Doesn't this way somehow affect my ad optimization? Will my ad network think the ads are still showing and refreshing even though they are hidden? What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why create the AdView if you're just going to hide it straight away? Create it and add it to the view hierarchy *only if* ads will be displayed. This way, there can be no confusion over whether a "hidden" banner still creates impressions in the advertising network.

Edit: To remove the view if it's already in the hierarchy, just call `[adView removeFromSuperview]`. You might want to release it as well (`[adView release]').

Comment: Oh ya well that's what I'm doing, but what if the user downloads the premium package and continues to use the app for 3 hours in one sitting-the ads will just be hidden, but will the network think they are still showing?

Comment: For that one off case (where they're still in a view with an ad banner, but have purchased the premium mode), I would either just not worry (it's going to be a very minor amount of the overall app usage), or just remove the ad banner when purchase occurs. You should only really hide views that you intend to show again later. If they're gone for good, remove them from the view hierarchy and destroy them.

Comment: what's stopping you from removing them as soon as they buy the in-app purchase? Why do you only hide them? Remove them from their views as soon as they purchase.

Comment: Lol well that's my question-how do I remove them? :)

Comment: adView release and adView=nil?

Comment: To remove the view, call `[adView removeFromSuperview]` after the user makes the purchase. And then make sure you release it.